# echo php code in xml file

Tags: php, mysql, xml

its me again with yet another query.If this is going to be too complexed then i wont even bother...so heres the query.

I have the title,artist,name of the person & dedication message stored in mysql.May be this is stupid..is it possible to create xml file to retrieve the above four information from the database. I have coded the below on the xml file but not sure whats missing.The config.php has database connection information.

Many thanks for your help!!!!
Nev

```
    <?php

require("config.php");



$i=0;
$db = "SELECT * FROM songlist WHERE songtype='S' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 50";
$db = "SELECT songlist.artist, songlist.title, requestlist.name, requestlist.msg FROM songlist, requestlist WHERE requestlist.name <> '' and requestlist.songID = songlist.ID ORDER BY requestlist.t_stamp DESC LIMIT 20";
$count = 1;

    while($results = $db->row())
    {
      $count++;

      if(($count % 2)== 0)

?>
<?php echo('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'); ?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">

<trackList>
  <track>

        <Song><?php echo $results['title']?></Song>
        <album><![CDATA[<?php echo $results['artist']; ?>]]></album>
    </track>

    </trackList>

</playlist>

<?
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when you run this?

Comment: You should be moving the XML preamble above the loop. Only the `<track>...</track>` should be printed out within the `while{}` loop. The closing `</trackList>` and `</playList>` should be outside of the loop too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained what your problem is? Also, I would need information on the format required for the xml, or what commands you'd need to send to your database code.

It looks like you have some formatting errors as well. I can only guess at what would work, but try this:

1) At the beginning of the file, you seem to have forgotten the  start tag
2) $i seems to be unused, delete it (?)
3) Your SQL statement is not only unenclosed in quotes, but would need to be sent to the database code (a complete guess since I don't know what's inside your config.php would be $db->query("your sql here");
4) delete:  '); ?>
5) ... actually this is getting silly, I should probably just rewrite it for you!!!

The thing is, before anything else, I'd need to know If you NEED to use the config.php? Or if I could code using native php functions.

But this is still fraught with problems (since I don't know what requirements the formatting for the xml are for one) but I'll give it a go! So just tell me if you need to use your config.php or not, then if no, I'll quickly code something. Otherwise you're going to have to post the contents of config.php

Cheers

Ok here's my best guess at what would work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
    <trackList>
<?php

$DB_SERVER = "localhost";
$DB_NAME = "yourdatabasename";
$DB_USER = "yourdbuser";
$DB_PASSWORD = "yourpw";

mysql_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($DB_NAME);

$sql = "select * from songlist order by date_added desc limit 10";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    ?>
        <track>
            <Song><![CDATA[<?= $result['title']?]]></Song>
            <album><![CDATA[<?= $result['artist']?>]]></album>
        </track>
    <?
}
?>
</trackList>
</playlist>
```

Just change your database name, user and password, then you will have your xml. However, you might want to change your album line above to:

Comment: I doubt $db = "your sql" will work! You'll need to say what database framework your config.php file uses, I suspect you'll need to call something like $db->query("your sql")

Comment: Many thanks for all the quick response!!! the config.php is the  provided by SAM Broadcaster templates. I have now replaced the config.php with dbconfigxml.php.Below is the code <?/* 
<CONFIG application="SAM" version="4.3.2">
 <Database>
  <Driver>MYSQL</Driver>
  <Host>localhost</Host>
  <Port>3306</Port>
  <Database>***</Database>
  <Username>***</Username>
  <Password>***</Password>
 </Database>
</CONFIG>

 */?>

Comment: I don't think you need to use that dbconfigxml.php, I'll quickly code something that you can use instead...

Comment: Thanks Jodes for that quick code. Now heres the error : XML Parsing Error: not well-formed <Song><?= $result['title']?></Song>
--------------------^

Comment: Ok, I've changed the line which specifies the <song>, I hope it works now!

Comment: Thank you Jodes,that code did the trick without any errors. Only sad issue is that I am unable to achieve what I wanted. Please nothing wrong with your XML code but its my idea that ain't working. Perhaps I will ask a separate question regarding my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your primary problem seems this:

```
$db = "SELECT * ..";
$db = "SELECT song ...";

    while($results = $db->row())
    {
```

You are assigning a string there, and immediately afterwards try to use it as some sort of database interface. Since I have no idea what is going on in your config script, or what weird database interface you use, it's easier explained with using the outdated mysql_functions:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT songlist.artist, ... goes here");

while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
```

The [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) runs your SELECT statement, and only then can you iterate over the results with [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) using the $result value that you got from mysql_query.

Note that you have to decide which of your two queries to actually run here. You cannot use two SELECT queries concurrently. (Or not not in your case at least.)