# flash text rotator xml

Tags: mysql, xml, flash, rotator

Ok so hereby I am starting a new topic after successful coding of xml file - Thanks to Jodes and others who have helped me with the solution. Now to the interesting part.

I am trying to produce flash text rotators from the xml file.Now i could do this in javascript which I have already implemented see link:[dedication message](http://www.tamilmelisai.com/live/newdedicationlist.php)

I want to display text instead of the image similarly like :[jw image rotator](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-image-rotator/)

Below is the code from **recently added xml**:`

$DB_SERVER = "localhost";
$DB_NAME = "yourdatabasename";
$DB_USER = "yourdbuser";
$DB_PASSWORD = "yourpw";

mysql_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);

$sql = "select * from songlist order by date_added desc limit 10";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    ?>
        
            
            ]]>
        
    

`

To call the xml file in html :`

```
<title>text Rotator</title>

<style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #fff; padding: 0 25px; color:#000; font: 13px/18px Arial, sans-serif; }
    a { color: #360; }
    h3 { padding-top: 50px; }
    ol { margin:5px 0 15px 16px; padding:0; list-style-type:square; }
</style>
```

```
<div id="container"><a href="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">Get the Flash Player</a> to see this rotator.</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s1 = new SWFObject("textrotator.swf","rotator","400","200","7");
    s1.addParam("allowfullscreen","false");
    s1.addVariable("file","**recently added.xml**");
    s1.addVariable("width","400");
    s1.addVariable("height","200");
    s1.write("container");
</script>
```

`

Overall I am having the following files: recently added.xml,recnetly added.html & recently added.swf
Please let me know if there is too much involved or guide if there is any flash based text rotator which can extract information from the database and display
many thanks and sorry for the big question!!!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your question is quite confusing. If i'm guessing right, you want:

A html page, containing a flash, which loads dynamic text, extracted as xml from a mysql database with the help of php?

If so you should have:

1x html file, which loads the swf.

1x flash file, which loads texts and rotates them.

1x php (or asp perhaps) file, which generates xml from the database and serves the flash.

Comment: All i wanted to achieve was a rotator like Jw rotator which displays text by pulling the information from mysql table. The display information on this page [link](http://www.tamilmelisai.com/live/newdedicationlist.php) has been coded using javascript method.But i want to do the same coding using jw rotator or any other flash text rotator which communicates with the database.

Comment: Let me get this straight, does your "recently added xml" file contain xml results? Where does it reside? Do you add the entire contents of it in your file variable?

Comment: recently added xml [link](http://tamilmelisai.com/live/image%20rotator/recently added.xml) , The xml was coded using the help from this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919035/echo-php-code-in-xml-file).I am not sure whether its outputs any results.All the files(swf,recently added xml recntly added html and swfobject.js reside under my webserver.

Comment: If you bothered to look at the link you posted, you'll notice that your xml file contains your php code. Your webserver does not execute php code in xml files. Rename the file to something .php and make sure that the return header is xml.